# What is the best way to get different join output in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am wondering which one is most efficient in spark to get below 4 frames

- df1 - left_anti
- df2 - left_semi
- df3 - right_anti
- df4 - right_semi

**Approach 1:** (join - 1, filter - 4)

```
merged_df = left_df.join(right_df, join_condition, how='full_outer')
df1 = merged_df.filter(sf.col('right_df.col1').isNull()).select('left_df.*')
df2 = merged_df.filter(sf.col('right_df.col1').isNotNull()).select('left_df.*')
df3 = merged_df.filter(sf.col('left_df.col1').isNull()).select('right_df.*')
df4 = merged_df.filter(sf.col('left_df.col1').isNotNull()).select('right_df.*')
```

**Approach 2:** (join - 4, filter - 0)

```
df1 = left_df.join(right_df, join_condition, how='left_anti')
df2 = left_df.join(right_df, join_condition, how='left_semi')
df3 = left_df.join(right_df, join_condition, how='right_anti')
df4 = left_df.join(right_df, join_condition, how='right_semi')
```

and

```
join_condition = (sf.col('left_df.col1') = sf.col('right_df.col1'))
```

Which of the above mentioned mechanisms is efficient?

Ref: https://medium.com/bild-journal/pyspark-joins-explained-9c4fba124839

**EDIT**
Consider `col1` to be primary key column (i.e. non-nullable) in both dataframes.

Comment: That would depend on what do you plan to do next (what action). As of now, both 1 and 2 only result in 4 execution plans.

Comment: I would like to perform equal operations on all 4 of them.. let's say writing to a hdfs location

Answer (score 3):

Before commenting on efficiency, just want to point out that generally speaking the `df_n` in both scenarios may not be identical:

```
>>> df1 = spark.createDataFrame([{'id1': 0, 'val1': "a"},{'id1': 1, 'val1': "b"},{'id1': None, 'val1': "df1"}])
>>> df2 = spark.createDataFrame([{'id2': 1, 'val2': "d"},{'id2': 2, 'val2': "e"},{'id2': None, 'val2': "df2"}])

>>> df1.show()
+----+----+
| id1|val1|
+----+----+
|   0|   a|
|   1|   b|
|null| df1|
+----+----+

>>> df2.show()
+----+----+
| id2|val2|
+----+----+
|   1|   d|
|   2|   e|
|null| df2|
+----+----+

>>> df1.join(df2, col("id1") == col("id2"), how="full_outer").show()                                                                 
+----+----+----+----+
| id1|val1| id2|val2|
+----+----+----+----+
|   0|   a|null|null|
|null| df1|null|null|
|null|null|null| df2|
|   1|   b|   1|   d|
|null|null|   2|   e|
+----+----+----+----+

>>> df1.join(df2, col("id1") == col("id2"), how="full_outer").filter(col('id2').isNull()).select(df1["*"]).show()
+----+----+
| id1|val1|
+----+----+
|   0|   a|
|null| df1|
|null|null|
+----+----+

>>> df1.join(df2, col("id1") == col("id2"), how="left_anti").show()
+----+----+
| id1|val1|
+----+----+
|   0|   a|
|null| df1|
+----+----+

>>> df1.join(df2, col('id1') == col('id2'), how='full_outer').filter(col('id2').isNotNull()).select(df1['*']).show()
+----+----+
| id1|val1|
+----+----+
|   1|   b|
|null|null|
+----+----+

>>> df1.join(df2, col('id1') == col('id2'), how='left_semi').show()
+---+----+
|id1|val1|
+---+----+
|  1|   b|
+---+----+
```

This is, of course, because of how `null`s are treated by SQL joins, and because the result of a `'full_outer'` join will contain all unmatched rows from both sides. The latter means that `k2.isNotNull()` filter used to create `df2` ("`semi-join`"), for example, will not eliminate any `null`-filled rows produced by right-hand keys that do not match anything on the left-hand side of a full outer join. For example:

```
>>> df1 = spark.createDataFrame([{'k1': 0, 'v1': "a"},{'k1': 1, 'v1': "b"},{'k1': 2, 'v1': "c"}])                                           
>>> df2 = spark.createDataFrame([{'k2': 2, 'v2': "d"},{'k2': 3, 'v2': "e"},{'k2': 4, 'v2': "f"}])
>>> df1.join(df2, col('k1') == col('k2'), how="full_outer").filter(col('k2').isNotNull()).select(df1["*"]).show()                           
+----+----+                                                                     
|  k1|  v1|
+----+----+
|null|null|
|   2|   c|
|null|null|
+----+----+
>>> df1.join(df2, col('k1') == col('k2'), how="left_semi").show()
+---+---+                                                                       
| k1| v1|
+---+---+
|  2|  c|
+---+---+
```

Comment: Yes, this is a valid point. Since the nulls are not equal. But I am interested in case when the data is not having nulls

Comment: Even with not null keys, the results of the semi-joins will be different from their "alternatives". Could I also ask you, next time, to clearly mark the changes in your question with "EDIT" or "UPDATE" or smth. Especially when the answers becomes somewhat irrelevant after an edit.

Comment: Sure, will highlight the updates. Can you point me to the case where both approaches return different results

Answer (score 0):

[Posting my answer hoping it could be revised by a more experienced user]

I'd say It won't matter. Spark will reorganize these operations for optimization so if in the end result is the same, then the DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph) and the execution plan will be kind of the same.

If the objective is performance, then 1 join would be more conveniente because  it can take advantage of a join broadcast (if the df at right is not too big and can be alocated in memory)